# Alias in ZF2 select - with calculated field

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, php-5.5

I want to create the following query with ZF2:

```
SELECT (a + b) AS c FROM ta WHERE c > 1;
```

with a table `ta` contain two integer fields `a` and `b`.

I tried it so far with this code:

```
$columns = array('c'=>'(a + b)');
$where = 'c > 1';
$tableGateway = $this->getTableGateway('ta');
$sql = $tableGateway->getSql();
$select = $sql->select()->columns($columns);
$select->where($where);    
$itemData = $tableGateway->selectWith($select);
```

Unfortunately the query given back is:

```
SELECT `ta`.`a + b` AS `c` FROM `ta` WHERE c > 1;
```

Any idea how to achieve that? I tried also without the brackets: `$columns = array('c'=>'a + b');` which does not work either.

I've tried it before with `$this->getAdapter()->query($sqlQuery, Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);` but I have run into an unbuffered query issue not resolvable with `->closeCursor()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression`:

```
$columns = array('c'=> new Expression('(ta.a + ta.b)'));
```